# Are there ways to format a source code to contain only one statement for each line?

Tags: c++, formatting

I want to know the automatic way formatting a c source code to contain only one statement for each line.

For example,

from this

```
1: if(true) break;
```

to this:

```
1: if(true)
2:     break;
```

Any useful comments would be appreciated. Thank you.

Note: Please read carefully what I want (only one statement per a line!). I have already tried Astyle and other beautifiers but those tools do not provide the function what I want. Also, I have searched it google, but no results have found.

Comment: i dont see an answer in the dupplicate link, for his question

Comment: @HansPassant: and just as many people would prefer that he didn't....  Pointless comment.

Comment: It looks like that Astyle does not have a function making a source code contain only one statement per a line. However, I closed this question because I expected no one knows a solution for the question exactly. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [AStyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) (Artistic Style).

**Usage Example :**

```
astyle --style=allman /home/user/project/foo.cpp
```

**Documentation :**

http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html

Comment: It looks like that Astyle does not have a function making a source code contain only one statement per a line. However, I closed this question because I expected no one knows a solution for the question exactly. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[Astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) is a tool that can reformat source code to any number of styles.

Answer (score 0):

There is [GNU indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent), it should be available for any Linux distribution and as part of CygWin under Windows. It is quite configurable (the default style is horrendous...). Or you could opt for [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or [xemacs](http://xemacs.org), both have configurable (auto)indentation for a variety of languages. Again, configure to taste, the defaults could hardly be worse.